# When is an HBase client Connection actually ready to use?

Tags: java, hbase

I am using HBase 1.1.0 and create HBase client connections like this:

```
try {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();                                                                                                               
    connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);  
}
catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info("Error {}", e);
}
```

However, I noticed that when ZooKeeper and HBase Master/Region servers are down, the `catch` clause is never reached. The code runs as if the connection is made, and `connection.isClosed()` returns `false`. So:

- What happens when I use this connection? Are the RPC calls buffered and retried at some interval in background?
- How can I tell whether the connection is actually ready for use? Should I try to do this, or just use it? My inclination is not to run a client service without the underlying datastores all actually ready, but perhaps this is not the idea with the new HBase API.
- Under what conditions is the `IOException` `catch` actually reached?

Comment: which version of hbase client do you use ?

Comment: @Udy I am using 1.1.0, Java

Comment: You should ideally be getting ZooKeeperConnectionException

Comment: @Peter thank you! I hadn't seen it, because it's not in the `.client` package. Either way, it inherits `IOException`.